# can't mount on /proc/cmdline

Tags: kernel, mount, kernel-parameters

I followed the this instructions in order to change the kernel boot args after boot:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters#Hijacking_cmdline

I created /root/cmdline , but when mounting I get:

```
root@linaro-developer:~# mount -n --bind -o ro /root/cmdline    /proc/cmdline                                                             
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
```

both files seems to exist:

```
root@linaro-developer:~# ls -l /proc/cmdline                                                                                           
-r--r--r-- 0 root root 231 May 11 14:17 /proc/cmdline

root@linaro-developer:~# ls -l /root/cmdline                                                                                           
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 251 May 11 14:26 /root/cmdline
```

I have Debian with kernel 4.4.23 on dragonboard410c which is arm64

I want to do it in order to turn on debugs on a builtin module.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not really sure what the point of that is, is there some program that checks `/proc/cmdline` for debug or other options but isn't started when the system starts, _and_ doesn't have any other way to set those options? I seem to recall that systemd checks the kernel command line for some settings at startup, but it's probably going have read it before you can bind mount anything anywhere...

Comment: That said, the bind mount works fine on my system. Do you have that `/root/cmdline` file? (And a mounted `/proc`?) Because that error message seems to hint that one of them might be missing, though at least Debian's `mount` is more verbose in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the drangonboard410c, I assume you are using U-Boot as a bootloader ?

If so, all kernel parameter are set inside boot.scr (or maybe uEnv.txt). 
In this case you can not overwrite the cmdline parameter and reboot the machine. It will not be persistant.

Please have a  look if /boot is mounted (or if there is a small boot partition on your eMMC / SD-card which can be mounted as /boot). Please let us know what you find inside, so we can help your real problem.

Comment: Hi, I use little kernel as a bootloader. also I dont want to reboot after changing the kernel args , is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to do it in order to turn on debugs on a builtin module.

Then hiding `/proc/cmdline` with a bind mount wouldn't help you. A bind mount on `/proc/cmdline` does not change the kernel arguments. It only shows different data to applications that read `/proc/cmdline`. Think of it as sticking a label on a box: it doesn't change what's in the box.

You can set some modules arguments through [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs). Look under `/sys/module/name_of_the_module/parameters` to see if the parameter you're interested in appears with write permission. If it does then you can change the value with e.g. `echo 1 >/sys/module/mymodule</em>/parameters/debug`. If the file is read-only or doesn't appear then there's no way to change the parameter at runtime. Even if you can change the parameter, there's no guarantee that the change has any effect: it depends how the module is written.